# BeautifulSoup freaking out when extracting movie script

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a movie script as text from [this website](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Thor-Ragnarok.html). It works great until a certain point, in which the text becomes like this:

```
5   .   

   /   b   &gt;   



                   T   H   E       W   A   L   L   S       C   O   M   E       A   L   I   V   E   !       A       s   e   e   m   i   n   g   l   y       i   n   f   i   n   i   t   e       s   w   a   r   m       o   f       F   I   R   E   

                   D   E   M   O   N   S       r   a   l   l   y       t   o       S   u   r   t   u   r   '   s       a   i   d   .
```

Here is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

website_url = requests.get("https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Thor-Ragnarok.html").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url, "lxml")
text = soup.pre
```

When printing out `text`, it shows the expected output until section 5., and then I get the text annoying above...

Any ideas on why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: Same code working fine in local setting. Might be your console issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `'html.parser'` instead of `'lxml'` and was able to display the entire script with proper formatting:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

website_url = requests.get("https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Thor-Ragnarok.html").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url, 'html.parser')
text = soup.pre
```

i.e. the beginning of section 5 was displayed as:

```
<b>                           BLUE DRAFT 05/20/16                   5.
</b>

    THE WALLS COME ALIVE! A seemingly infinite swarm of FIRE
    DEMONS rally to Surtur's aid.

<b>                         THOR
</b>               I make grave mistakes all the time.
               Everything seems to work out.

    In the shadows, a massive FIRE DRAGON ROARS.

    The fire demons SURGE FORWARD. Thor backs up, HAMMERING
    AWAY. He then leaps back, SPRINGBOARDS off the wall, and-
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I should have thought about trying a different parser.

Comment: You're quite welcome, I'm glad to hear that solved it for you!

Answer (score 0):

Odd...
I tried your original code on my machine and I am unable to reproduce the spacing problems you describe.
I have lxml-4.3.0, bs4 version 4.7.1, and python 3.7.1.
What versions do you have?

Comment: I have Python 3.6.7, bs4 4.6.3 and I don't know how to check the lxml version. Anyway, changing lxml to html.parser worked, so it must have been a problem with my lxml version!